# feed a dictionary-like argument to a class

Tags: python, dictionary, class, arguments

I am using a package where I need to build a class object for each of my experiments (many) and each time I need to feed too many variables into the class.

the class source code looks like:

```
.
.
.
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        keys_to_set = [
            'key1',
            'key2',
            'key3',
            .
            .
            'keyN']
.
.
.
```

Now, I want to create .csv files for each experiment, and feed the class through an automated manner e.g. with a dictionary, however dictionary as arguments does not work for me and get errors!

I'm out of ideas, I don't know if there are any "dictionary-like" structures that may help me here. any helps/tips would be appreciated!

**to make it a bit clear maybe:**

if I want to make an object like `test_obj` like this:

```
test_obj = Class(key1=val1,
                 key2=val2,
                 .
                 .
                 keyN=valN)
```

is there any way that I can pass the argument as a dictionary-type thing like:

```
test_dict = {key1: val1, ...., keyN: valN}
test_obj = Class(test_dict)
```

(apparently dictionary can not do the job as I have tested)

Comment: x = MyClass(**my_dictionary) That's how you call it if you have a dict named my_dictionary which is just the kwargs in dict format. I am not sure what you're doing with keys_to_set which is just a list of constants.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I think they are looking to set instance values by name based in the keys in the passed dictionary. OP, have you looked at just assigning your passed dictionary to `self.__dict__`?  That might be a simple solution if it happens to work

Comment: Are you looking to essentially create a class dynamically based on passing it a dictionary?

Comment: @KennyOstrom would you take another look... I tried to make my point a little more clear maybe... thanks...

Comment: @JonSG Thank you... yes... I would like to pass a dictionary as the argument... made a little edit to the post if you could take another look... as far as I understood your solution it involves altering the source code which I can't since my code needs to work on running the standard package...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking to do one of these two things:

This creates an instance based completely on passing a dictionary.

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, data):
        for key, value in data.items():
            self.__setattr__(key, value)
foo = Foo({"foo": 1, "bar": 2})
print(foo.foo, foo.bar)
```

Alternatively, this does the same in this particular case.

```py
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.__dict__ = data
foo = Foo({"foo": 1, "bar": 2})
print(foo.foo, foo.bar)
```

Perhaps though, your constructor is less dynamic and you want to pass it key value pairs based on a dictionary. In that case you might:

```py
class Bar():
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
bar = Bar(**{"foo": 1, "bar": 2})
print(bar.foo, bar.bar)
```

All examples should result in:

```
1 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much... it helped a lot... as a matter of fact the solution was in double asterisks **dict... I didn't know about it! a shame!